# Elasticsearch: Query nested object contained within an object

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm struggling to build a query where I can do a nested search across a sub-object of a document.

Say I have the following index/mapping:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/author/" -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "item": {
            "properties": {
                "books": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "nested"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

And the following 2 documents in the index:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Robert Louis Stevenson",
    "books": {
        "count": 2,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "label": "Treasure Island"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "label": "Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Philip K. Dick",
    "books": {
        "count": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "label": "Do Android Dream of Electric Sheep"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have an array of Book ID's, say `[1,4]`; how would I write a query which does a keyword search of the author name AND only returns them if they wrote one of the books in the array?

I haven't managed to get a query which doesn't cause some sort of query `parse_exception`, but as a starting block, here's the current iteration of my query - maybe it's obvious where I'm going wrong?

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "label": "Louis"
                }
            }
        },
        "nested": {
            "path": "books.data",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "terms": {
                            "books.data.id": [
                                1,
                                4
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 8
}
```

In the above scenario I'd like the document for Mr Robert Louis Stevenson to be returned, as his name contains `Louis` and he wrote book ID `1`.

For what it's worth, the current error I get looks like this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "author",
            "node": "sCk3su4YSnqhvdTGjOztlw",
            "reason": {
               "type": "parse_exception",
               "reason": "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

This makes me feel like I've got my "nested" object all wrong, but the docs suggest that I'm right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it almost right, the `nested` query must simply be located inside the `bool` one like in the query below. Also the `match` query needs to be made on the `name` field since this is where the author name is stored:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Louis"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "books.data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "terms": {
                    "books.data.id": [
                      1,
                      4
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 8
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track. I also needed to place my `must` and `nested` objects into an array... subtle!